# Second derivative of $\int_\mathbb{R}\cos(tx)dp(x)$

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory, derivatives

Let $p$ be a probability on $\mathbb{R}$ and 
$$f(t):=\int_\mathbb{R}\cos(tx)dp(x).$$
I want to show that if $f''(0)$ exists then $$f''(0)=\lim_{t\to 0}2\frac{f(t)-1}{t^2} \: \:(\star).$$

By differentiation under the integral sign, I obtain
$$f''(t)=\int_\mathbb{R}-x^2\cos(tx)dp(x).$$
Now, it seems that I need a sort of "integration by parts for probabilities", but I don't know if something similar exists.

So what's the fastest way to deduce $(\star)$?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "let $p$ be a probability on $\mathbb R$"? Is $p$ a distribution function?

Comment: @Math1000: yes, a probability distribution

Comment: Your procedure is correct only if the "derivative" converges. So you need extra assumptions on $p(x)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that  $f(0)=1$ and $f'(0)=0$. Using Taylor in $0$ we have 
$$f(t)=f(0)+f'(0)t+\frac{f''(0)}{2}t^2+o(t^2).$$
Therefore $$f''(0)=2\frac{f(t)-f(0)-f'(0)t}{t^2}+o(1)=2\frac{f(t)-1}{t^2}+o(1).$$

Comment: Sorry, I can't comprehend this. Shouldn't $f''(t)$ be $f(t)$  in the first place?

Comment: @HandeBruijn: Yes. Typo. Sorry.

Comment: OK. And how about the $o(t^2)$? Shouldn't that be $o(t^3)$?

Comment: @HandeBruijn: Nope. It's the "little-o" notation, not the "big-O" one.

Comment: OK. Can't we say that $f''(0)=2\frac{f(t)-1}{t^2}+O(t)$?

Comment: @HandeBruijn: Yes, but what's the point?

Comment: Then the limit in the question can be done, because $O(t)\to 0$.

Comment: @HandeBruijn: You can solve the problem with the "big-O" notation, I solved it with the "little-o" one. It's the same thing!

Comment: @HandeBruijn: maybe, you don't understand what $o(1)$is?

Comment: It is not clear that differentiation under the integral produces an integral that converges.

Comment: I think that this proofs omits many important details about the convergence of the various integrals encountered and about the possibility to permute limits and integrals, or derivatives and integrals, and precisely these are the difficult parts of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

1) Using Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem (LDCT), you may commute $\lim \limits _{t \to 0}$ and $\int \limits _{\Bbb R}$, so that

$$\lim \limits _{t \to 0} \big( f(t) - 1 \big) = \lim \limits _{t \to 0} f(t) - 1 = \lim \limits _{t \to 0} \int \limits _{\Bbb R} \cos (tx) \Bbb d p - 1 = \int \limits _{\Bbb R} \lim \limits _{t \to 0} \cos (tx) \Bbb d p - 1 = \int \limits _{\Bbb R} 1 \Bbb d p - 1 = 0 ,$$

therefore one may apply L'Hospital's theorem to obtain $\lim \limits _{t \to 0} 2 \dfrac {f(t) - 1} {t^2} = \lim \limits _{t \to 0} \dfrac {f'(t)} t$.

2) *We must now make the assumption that the identity function $x : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is Lebesgue-integrable, or else I suspect your claim to be false!*

Using LDCT a second time, one may show that the derivative commutes with the integral, i.e $f'(t) = \dfrac {\Bbb d} {\Bbb d t} \int \limits _{\Bbb R} \cos (tx) \Bbb d p = \int \limits _{\Bbb R} \dfrac {\Bbb d} {\Bbb d t} \cos (tx) \Bbb d p = \int \limits _{\Bbb R} -x \sin (tx) \Bbb d p$, essentially because $| \int \limits _{\Bbb R} -x \sin (tx) \Bbb d p | \le \int \limits _{\Bbb R} |-x \sin (tx)| \Bbb d p \le \int \limits _{\Bbb R} |x|\Bbb d p < \infty$ by the afore-mentioned assumption.

3) Using LDCT a third time like in step 1), it is easy to show that $\lim \limits _{t \to t_0} f'(t) = f'(t_0) \ \forall t_0 \in \Bbb R$ (i.e. that $f'$ is continuous). In particular, $\lim \limits _{t \to 0} f'(t) = f'(0) = 0$. Therefore, one may apply L'Hospital's theorem a second time to get $\lim \limits _{t \to 0} \dfrac {f'(t)} t = \lim \limits _{t \to 0} \dfrac {f''(t)} 1 = f''(0)$.

We have obtained that $f''(0)$ exists and is equal to $\lim \limits _{t \to 0} 2 \dfrac {f(t) - 1} {t^2}$.